# Android AlertDialog EditText dismiss error

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have to get a password from user via AlertDialog and EditText. When user opens this AlertDialog and then presses **Cancel** or **back button**, it disappears normally. However when user opens this AlertDialog again, application will be broken. My code here, where am I making mistake?

```
sifrePencere.setTitle("Çıkış");
sifrePencere.setMessage("Uygulamayı kapatmak için lütfen şifreyi giriniz:");
sifrePencere.setView(sifre);

sifrePencere.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        String girilenSifre = sifre.getText().toString();

        SQLiteDatabase db = vt.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor kayit = db.rawQuery("SELECT sifre FROM CocukTableti", null);
        kayit.moveToFirst();

        if (girilenSifre.equals(kayit.getString(0))) {

            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

        } else {

            dialog.dismiss();
            dialog.cancel();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Girilen şifre hatalı!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
});

sifrePencere.setNegativeButton("Vazgeç", null);

sifrePencere.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of your code write

```
mybuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

and before

```
sifrePencere.show():
```

write this statement

```
myAlertDialog = mybuilder.create();
```

Comment: Could you please tell it editing my code? By the way I've already written new AlertDialog.Builder(this); on top..

Answer (score 0):

I was showing this AlertDialog in OptionsMenu. But I defined the variables on top of my codes. So, error comes from here. I defined these variables into OnOptionsItemClick, it fixed!